# Linkedin API. How do I get a pop window which asks user to click on allow and automatically get the code instead of copying and pasting in Linkedin

Tags: java, eclipse, linkedin-api

```
//Linkedin API 
 public AuthHandler(OAuthService serviceProvider)
 {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Token requestToken = serviceProvider.getRequestToken();
System.out.println(serviceProvider.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
System.out.print(">>");
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine()); //no errors in the code
accessToken = serviceProvider.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
}
```

// Here iam requesting the accesstoken
// I got the url

Comment: I need to copy the url into webbrower, then i have to click on allow it for the app, then it generates a code and i have to paste the code in the console window and press enter to generate the accesstoken.Instead of doing this I want the code to open a popup window for the user and then he clicks on the allow button, then code is automatically copied to generate the access token. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think specifying the call back url option does this , and copy pasting of the code is for oauth integration for desktop apps and not web apps